# Whoosh not searching words with accent

Tags: python, full-text-search, whoosh

I'm using Whoosh to implement a tiny local search engine. Documents contain both French and English languages.

As you may know, accents (`à` `è` `é` ...) are frequently used in the French language. So I had to deal with them using the accent folding as suggested by the [Whoosh Documentation](http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stemming.html):

```
accent_analyzer = RegexAnalyzer(r'\w+') | LowercaseFilter() \
                  | StopFilter() | CharsetFilter(accent_map)

schema = Schema(path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT(analyzer=accent_analyzer))
```

Indexing documents work just fine (no error).

But when it comes to search, I get no results for words that contain accents.

For e.g.

Let document `D` with `content = u'unité logique'` :

- Searching using `logique` hits the documents.
- Searching using `unité` doesn't.
- Searching using `unite` doesn't.

So I suppose the index writer is ignoring words with accents that's why it shows no results for queries against these words whether the queries contained an accent or not.

Just a reminder that what I want to achieve is hitting the document `D` using both words `unité` and `unite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whoosh requires all strings to be in unicode

[Does whoosh require all strings to be unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897042/does-whoosh-require-all-strings-to-be-unicode)

for accent in unicode see http://unicodelookup.com/

(https://ss64.com/unicode-accents.html)

Comment: Yes, the issue was that I was using `'unicode_escape'` as the content encoding.